# non-professional question about Steven Avery trial

Tags: trial

I have just watched the TV series Making a Murderer and have a question regarding the trial with S. Savery and B. Dassey. Whose was the decision that there would be two separate trials. Was it Judge's, Prosecution's or Defence's decision. I would await that given the fact that these two men were according to the prosecution acomplices they would be judged together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision on who to try together is initially made by the prosecutor. A defendant can move to be tried separately.

I can find no record of such a motion but it may have occurred.

I suspect the reason they were tried separately was because Dassey was a minor.
*State v. Dassey*, 2013 WI App 30 (Wis. Ct. App. 2013)